# How does Angel have a brain the size of a planet?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was walking through Sawtooth Cauldron, and got an ECHO recording with the following dialog:

> **Handsome Jack**: So what's this Zero guy doing on Pandora in the first place?
>  **Angel**: I dunno.
>  **Handsome Jack**: *Angel, you've got a brain the size of a planet.* Don't give me 'I dunno.
>  **Angel**: From what footage we have of him, I can't even tell if Zero's human or not.
>  **Handsome Jack**: W-w-what do you mean, not human? Is he a robot? An alien? What?
>  **Angel**: I dunno.

(Copied from [here](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0/ECHO_Recorders))

I originally interpreted this as Angel's computer "brain", which could be huge for all we know.

At this point in the story though, we already know that Angel

> is a siren, not an AI; and obviously Jack knew this all along.

As you can see from the image below:

> [image]
>  Her head is clearly not the size of a planet, since this image is from when she's standing right in front of you.

What does Jack mean by this?

Comment: Handsome Jack **never** uses hyperbole, no siree...

Comment: @Frank Using exaggeration doesn't make sense in this case. Her head doesn't appear to be any larger than normal, and nothing indicates that she's exceptionally smart, except for her ability to access the network.

Comment: "except for her ability to access the network" - is it not possible she has access to computers to help her?  Also, I've been told I have a brain the size of the moon before, so it's a realistic exaggeration:  it's not necessarily referring to the literal size of her brain, but to her intelligence.

Comment: Is this not a reference to 'The Hitchhikers guide to the galaxy' - Marvin the paranoid android constantly references the fact he has a brain the size of a planet, and no one cares.

Comment: Here I am, brain the size of planet, and you ask me how Angel has a brain the size of a planet? Call that "_job satisfaction_"? 'Cuz I don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by djsmiley2k in the comments, this is indeed just an Easter egg statement in reference to the 'Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy'.

> In the second Lost ECHO recording detailing Zer0's backstory, Handom Jack tells Angel she's "got a brain the size of a planet", which is reference to Marvin the depressed android's "brain the size of a planet" lament.

[Reference](https://www.wattpad.com/27051268-borderlands-2-easter-egg-collections-easter-egg)

Looking at Jack's statement in regards to what it means about Angel you would think that it is referencing the fact that her Siren power is "Artificial Intelligence". Her father Jack is also a programmer for Hyperion which may be related the reason she has the power of Artificial Intelligence.

[Some Background Information on Angel](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Angel)

Comment: Not to mention that Angel was connected to most Hyperion network, which means that she had access to a lot of databases and machines to work at her desire.

Comment: I think the more important answer is that she is networked with all the computers on the planet, to the point I almost downvoted this.

Answer (score 3):

Angel has a neural interface that networks her with all the Hyperion computers on Pandora.

You can see this throughout the Borderlands games, when she speaks through and exerts direct control over computers.

So, although the statement is not literally true in regards to the organic brain in her skull, Angel *effectively* has a brain the size of a planet, because her neural network covers Pandora's surface (as well as satellites in orbit).